# Windows Authentication Popup Behaving Differently Between Windows 7 And Windows 10

Tags: asp.net-core, browser, windows-authentication

We have an application aspnetcore 3.1 windows authentication configurated.

**2 client have same options like**

- Checked Enable Integrated Windows Authentication*
- Local Internet > User Authentication > Logon > Automatic logon with current user name and password
- There is no trusted site

Behavior Windows 7 Client

1. Browser cache clean
2. Go to application url
3. Windows Authentication popup shows

Behavior Windows 10 Client

1. Browser cache clean
2. Go to application url
3. Windows Authentication popup does not show and automatically login

*What is the differences between windows 7 and windows 10?

How do I automatically login for windows 7 client too?*

Comment: What Browsers are involved? what kind of configuration do you have? Is it running on the local machine or in production? There is no support offered for window 7. There are so many questions. I think you should find a way to present the problem with less "variables" in a more narrow context for us to find an answer for you.

Comment: Chrome browser and Eo browser we tried both.
Application is running at production windows server on iis